# Wordpress theming a plugin custom php page with the same selected theme

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, theming

I'm writing a plugin that is a gateway to a merchant server. The plugin is activated by a shortcode and then it shows a confirmation page. The confirmation page will get the user to the bank and it will get back to an OK or KO page of the plugin.

These two pages are into the plugin folder and I want their look and feel similar to the blog (almost for header and footer).

I cannot call the get_header or get_footer because they are not included.

Is there a workaround to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your file and let me know:

```
<?
include_once('../../../wp-load.php');
get_header() ?>
```

Comment: That's great :) Would you please mind marking it as the answer then? It could help somebody else in near future . Thanks :-)